# How to remove the log title in java

Tags: java, logging

When I do log in java. For every log information , It will begin with a title line like this,

```
Aug 9, 2012 11:19:13 AM com.aures.IBDownload.ContractHistoryDataDownloader logActivity
```

`com.aures.IBDownload.ContractHistoryDataDownloader` is the java class name, `logActivity` is the log name

The text after time is only showed in console. In log file, It's just time.

Now I want to remove the txt after the time in console as well, because It is so long and repeats every time, so annoying.

Any ideas,Thanks!!

Comment: What logging framework/library are you using? How is it currently configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using log4j, find your log4j.xml or log4j.properties and change the log format.  There'll probably be a character after the date & class (from memory it's [d] [c] or similar) which will be representing the log file name.  Just remove that character & the brackets around it, and you should be right. :)

Comment: Thanks. But If I just use java build-in log functions instead of log4j. How should I do that? Any way?

Comment: I'm not sure, haven't used Java's built in ones before.  If you're using Maven (smart man... :) ) then I'd really recommend adding the log4j packages to your project.  It'll be a lot easier and have some additional features.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will have a try.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `java.util.logging`, then (from my reading of the documentation), you need to write a custom `Formatter` class to change the log file format.  The standard class libraries provide a `SimpleFormatter` class, but it doesn't seem to provide any way for you to tweak the format.

Comment: Thanks. Seems there is no way to implement this in console. You are right, the Formatter class is just to format the log file. I need to turn to log4j.